# How to pass a Java null parameter to a native method that uses JNA to compile to C code?

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, jna

I'm trying to use a [Java library](https://github.com/Zubnix/udev-java-bindings) that wraps the C library [libudev](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/libudev.html). One of the methods I need to call, `addMatchSubsystemDevtype(final String subsystem, final String devtype)`, takes two String parameters, the second of which needs to be a `null`. An example of this in C code can be seen [here](http://www.signal11.us/oss/udev/) (ctrl+f null). However when I attempt to do this in Java, JNA throws a `NullPointerException`, as can be seen here:

```
Monitor monitor = Monitor.newFromNetlink(udev, "udev");
monitor.addMatchSubsystemDevtype("video4linux", null);
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.jna.Native.getBytes(Native.java:604)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.toByteArray(Native.java:627)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.toByteArray(Native.java:620)
    at org.freedesktop.libudev.jna.StringUtil.asPointer(StringUtil.java:14)
    at org.freedesktop.libudev.Monitor.addMatchSubsystemDevtype(Monitor.java:116)
    at Example.main(Example.java:14)
```

Is there any way I can pass a null to this C method from Java?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @EJP This isn't a "why isn't this code working" question. This is a question for how to pass a null value to a Java native method. Please explain how the problem statement is not clear.

Comment: The question should not be , however; "how to pass a null value to native via JNA" but "how to pass a null value to the udev-java-bindings library". JNA can handle nulls just fine. It's the library method that doesn't check for null. Looks easy to fix, however.

Comment: @user2543253 Thank you! I wasn't aware of that and the stack trace pointing to `...jna.StringUtil.asPointer` led me down the wrong path of thinking it was a JNA issue. I now realize it was a problem with the library, like you said, and have fixed it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user2543253 pointed out that it isn't a JNA issue but an issue with the Java library. I fixed the issue by simply adding

```
public int addMatchSubsystem(final String subsystem) {
    return UdevLibrary.INSTANCE().udev_monitor_filter_add_match_subsystem_devtype(
            getPointer(), StringUtil.asPointer(subsystem), null);
}
```

to the library's Monitor class.